# Copy cell to another sheet if condition is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet with a large data array, which I would like to split into several sheets based on values in a column.

In the main sheet, column "A", I have various labels. On the new sheet, e.g. "LabelX" i need to extract all rows from main sheet, corresponding to "LabelX" value in column "A". There are multiple rows with same label.

Hope it makes sense,

Basic example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you want to have your data sorted.
If your columns in your data and in your result are in the same order and you use Office365 this can be done using:
`=SORT(FILTER(MainSheet!A:D,A:A<>""))`
(Replace `MainSheet!` with the actual sheet name of your main sheet).

or if you want the results for one particular Label only (for example: Label1) you can loose SORT:
`=FILTER(MainSheet!A:D,A:A="Label1")`.